# ¿Cómo puedo usar en ASP.NET MVC5 nombres de usuarios con "/" barras?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, url, crud

Estoy usando `Visual Studio 2017` `ASP.NET` con `Entity Framework 5`, genero automáticamente el `CRUD` con las funciones del `Entity Framework`, el problema es que al editar un usuario, por ejemplo "DOMAIN-NN\username", el cual es el ID de la tabla de usuarios, `ASP.NET` lo usa como parámetro en la `url` para dirigirse a la página donde se editará el usuario, el problema es que la barra invertida se interpreta como %5C http://localhost:60763/LC_USR/Edit/DOMAIN-NN%5Cusername y no encaja con ninguna ruta.

He buscado bastante antes de realizar esta pregunta. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar? Muchas gracias!

Comment: Has probado con agregar una ruta que tenga dos parámetros el dominio por un lado y el username por otro? Así no interfiere la barra . Avisanos o sino armamos un ejemplo. Yo iría por esta solucion ya que es un problema de ruteo y en mvc tenemos control de este tema.

Comment: Hola José, en el username ya está agregado el dominio, y se usa todo como ID, su formato es DOMAIN-NN\username, hice lo que me propusiste pero de igual manera no aceptaba, ya que no puedo separar el ID en dos parametros, ejemplo: url: ´{controller}/{action}/{DOMAIN-NN}%5C{id}´ El parámetro que dice {id} vuelve a ser DOMAIN-NN\username

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa viable sería enviar el **id** del usuario en una variable en el **Querystring** de la siguiente manera:

[http://localhost:60763/LC_USR/Edit?id=DOMAIN-NN\username](http://localhost:60763/LC_USR/Edit?id=DOMAIN-NN%5Cusername)

Para que esto funcione, deberás **modificar la ruta por defecto** "**Default**" de tu aplicación para que el **id** del usuario se pase al Controlador desde el **Querystring** y **no** desde la **ruta**. La ruta "Default" quedaría así:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
        );
```

Entonces, para las acciones de tu CRUD que **requieran el id del usuario** deberás modificarlas de la siguiente manera:

Por ejemplo para EDIT sería así:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = @item.USERID })
```

Comment: Hola Rafael, buena observacion, pero me he equivocado en la pregunta (ya la he editado). La barra invertida se traduce a %5C (que es el signo de barra invertida para urls) y esto no es admitido en la configuracion de rutas de asp.net

Comment: @vrecalde: Si escribes directamente en el navegador esto:  http://localhost:60763/LC_USR/Edit/DOMAIN-NN\username te funciona?

Comment: No, me convierte la barra invertida en barra normal y el error es 404.

Comment: También he probado lo que me has dicho primero, en el momento de formacion de la url para ir a la pagina de edicion: @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = @Html.Encode(item.USERID) }) pero tampoco me ha funcionado, error 404 y la url queda: http://localhost:60763/LC_USR/Edit/DOMAIN-NN%5Cusername

Comment: @vrecalde: Y si pruebas de esta manera  http://localhost:60763/LC_USR/Edit?id=DOMAIN-NN\username te funciona?

Comment: me funciona de maravilla, voy a ver como construir una ruta para que acepte eso. Muchisimas gracias.